# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, android-sdk-tools

My`ionic info`

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

So after i try to make a apk like `ionic build android` in my mac. It shows this error. I tried to remove the android platform and i ran it again. But i am getting same issue. Any one else facing same issue ??

**Error: /Users/apple/Desktop/Working Projects/IOnic 1/Paassneet/19:4:17 5.00 pm/pass/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain**

Thanks

Comment: what does `cordova requirements` give? and what is your codrova android platform version?

Comment: @suraj   any solution.....can u please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244660/menu-is-not-working-when-i-push-the-screen-ionic-3